# UDP Multicasting From Mobile to PC

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, android-wifi

I am making an Android Application to send UDP Multicast Packets from mobile to my PC.

This is code for my mobile application:

This is the user permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

**DeviceManagerWindow.java**

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;

public class DeviceManagerWindow extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_manager_window);
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService( Context.WIFI_SERVICE );
        if(wifi != null)
        {
            WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = wifi.createMulticastLock("WifiDevices");
            lock.acquire();
        }
        Thread sendMulticast = new Thread(new MultiCastThread());
        sendMulticast.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.device_manager_window, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This file sends multicast packets:

**MultiCastThread.java**

```
public class MultiCastThread implements Runnable
{
    MulticastSocket s;
    DatagramPacket pack;
    public MultiCastThread()
    {
        try
        {
            s = new MulticastSocket(WifiConstants.PORT_NO);
            s.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(WifiConstants.GROUP_ADDR));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Socket Error: ",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            pack = new DatagramPacket(WifiConstants.WHO_IS.getBytes(),WifiConstants.WHO_IS.getBytes().length, InetAddress.getByName(WifiConstants.GROUP_ADDR), WifiConstants.PORT_NO);
            s.setTimeToLive(WifiConstants.TIME_TO_LIVE);
            s.send(pack);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Packet Sending Error: ",e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**WifiConstants.java**

This file keeps records of the constants for Wifi Interaction.

```
public class WifiConstants
{
    public static final int PORT_NO = 5432;
    public static final String GROUP_ADDR = "225.4.5.6";
    public static final int DGRAM_LEN = 1024;
    public static final String WHO_IS = "Who is?";
    public static final int TIME_TO_LIVE = 1;
}
```

On my system I am running a java code to receive the packets and print it in the console.

**ListenerDevice.java**

```
package Receiver;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;


public class ListenerDevice
{
    public static final int PORT_NO = 5432;
    public static final String GROUP_ADDR = "225.4.5.6";
    public static final int DGRAM_LEN = 1024;
    public static final String WHO_IS = "Who is?";
    public static final int TIME_TO_LIVE = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MulticastSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket inPacket = null;
        byte[] inBuf = new byte[DGRAM_LEN];
        try
        {
          //Prepare to join multicast group
          socket = new MulticastSocket(PORT_NO);
          InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(GROUP_ADDR);
          socket.joinGroup(address);

              while(true)
              {
                    System.out.println("Listening");
                    inPacket = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, inBuf.length);
                    socket.receive(inPacket);
                    String msg = new String(inBuf, 0, inPacket.getLength());
                    System.out.println("From :" + inPacket.getAddress() + " Msg : " + msg);
              }
        }
        catch(Exception ioe)
        {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
      }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong I am not getting any output.
Please Help.
I saw many tutorials and followed each and every step they said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the devices should be connected to the same **network**. As you are sending packet from the Emulator to the PC, it resides on the same system. Therefore, you are not facing any problem with it. But as you will send the data packets from PC to the mobile device both the devices should share the same network.

It would be more **efficient** if both the devices connected to `unfirewalled` network. because firewall could create trouble in sending the data packets.

This is the conclusion I came upto.